# How to return from pcap_loop() or pcap_dispatch() without using pcap_breakloop() within the callback function

Tags: c, pcap

If you use blocking `pcap_loop()` or `pcap_dispatch()` to handle incoming packet data via a suitable callback fn you may have a requirement to break out of those functions, i.e. get them to return.

Now `pcap_breakloop()` is a means to do this, but that doesn't work if you call it from another thread of execution. You can call `pcap_breakloop()` from within the callback fn specified in `pcap_loop()`/`pcap_dispatch()` but this is only an option if you can guarantee a pkt is going to trigger the callback.

How can one break a `pcap_loop()` or `pcap_dispatch()` in the absence of an incoming packet to trigger the callback fn?

If `pcap_loop()`/`pcap_dispatch()` is blocked in this use-case scenario, then you're going to want to unblock it from a different thread. But you can't call `pcap_breakloop()` from a different thread of execution.

I read the man page and it mentioned something about using signals, but these are non-portable OS specific.

The only work-around I can see to this problem is using `pcap_dispatch()` but in unblocking mode (`pcap_setnonblock()`). You can then put `pcap_dispatch()` in a tight while-loop. This works but I think it would be more elegant to be able to politely ask `pcap_loop()` or `pcap_dispatch()` to return from another thread?

Comment: The callback is executed in the *same* thread?!

Comment: thats a fair point, i can see thats the only place where you can call pcap_breakloop() from. But theres two issues, 1) how do you inform the callback from another thread that you want to call pcap_breakloop()? 2) in the situation where no pkts are being received the callback is not getting called, so how do you call pcap_breakloop() then?

Comment: My use-case is I want to close a pkt listener thread gracefully and very often at the point I want to close it, there are no longer any pkts being received. So the callback route doesn't work in this scenario

Comment: have revised the OP to improve clarity as to what I am asking

Comment: Do you want the solution to be portable and if not what OS and what capturing device are you targeting?

Comment: yes the solution has to be portable, i.e. linux and windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can one break a pcap_loop() or pcap_dispatch() in the absence of an incoming packet to trigger the callback fn?

On UN*Xes, catch a signal such as `SIGUSR1`, have the signal handler do nothing, and, after calling `pcap_breakloop()`, call `pthread_kill()` to send that signal to the thread that's doing the `pcap_dispatch()` or `pcap_loop()`.  When you catch the signal, do *not* specify `SA_RESTART`; that way, the signal will interrupt system calls such as the call made by libpcap to read the captured packets.  That's UN*X-specific, but it's not specific to particular versions of UN*X.

On Windows, use `pcap_getevent()` to get the "event handle for the `pcap_t`, and use `SetEvent()` on that handle after calling `pcap_breakloop()`.

Comment: many thanks for the response, but what a nightmare! Do you think possibly my use of pcap_setnonblock() is a simpler means to cross platform implementation? I'm just worried whether it will create some 'tight-loop' performance issue for the pkt capture thread. I'll have to test performance of the mod carefully..

Comment: Yes, it's a pain; libpcap, and `pcap_breakloop()`, weren't designed for a multi-threaded world.  If you use non-blocking mode, your capture loop will consume an entire CPU core while it's running - it can be preempted, so it won't eat the entire core, but it might take CPU away from other threads and processes; you'll have to try it to see how much of a problem it is.

Comment: thanks for the additional context - performance is key here so eating a core definitely not preferable. I could simply not care about tidying up the thread nicely on closing as it only occurs when the whole process is also being closed so possibly it doesn't matter if violently closing the pcap listener thread leaks a bit of memory? That could be a lesser evil than consuming a whole core unecessarily

Comment: If you care *only* about Linux and Windows, *and* you're willing to compile the libpcap master branch from source (combining it with the WinPcap or Npcap driver and packet.dll in the case of Windows), on those two *particular* platforms `pcap_breakloop()` will force a wakeup of the thread using `pcap_loop()` or `pcap_dispatch()`.  That is *not* guaranteed on other platforms (e.g., macOS/\*BSD/Solaris 11 or Solaris 10/HP-UX or AIX or IRIX or Tru64 UNIX).

Comment: Or you *could* forcibly terminate the pcap listener thread, as long as that thread isn't doing something that, if terminated at some random point, won't leave data structures in an inconsistent state.